# How to control the access to certain Nodeport from external via iptables

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

We have a lot of services set up by Nodeport and available from external via `<node_ip>:<node_port>`.

It should be a common requirement that I would like to control the access to certain services, which means the requests from some of IPs may access to it, while others not.

We'd like to use `iptables` to meet this requirement, which gets a lot of **confusion** since kubernetes use it to set up communication as well. 
Do we have any high-level `guidance` to design/create iptable rule to control k8s service?

Specifically, I am confused in below areas:

1. Which table should I append rules into?  I find that lots of rules in `nat and filter` are created by K8s
2. If I what to disable the access of service from one external IP to certain node, such as 
   `telnet <node_ip>:<node_port>`
   should I REJECT on `FORWARD` or `INPUT`, or `PREROUTING` directly?
3. Do these rules depend on specific network plugins (eg flannel or weave)? Whether different plugins have a different way to config rule or not?

For my scenarios, I have below rules to be set up:

1. all nodes in the cluster should have `full access`to each other
2. some core services (API) should only be **ACCEPT** by `certain` IPs
3. certain services in a port range can be **ACCEPT** by `all` IPs
4. **REJECT** the access to `any other` services from all IPs (outside of cluster)

k8s version: 1.9.5
network plugin: weave

Best Regards!

/triage support

Answer (score 2):

Although you can change iptables on your K8s nodes, I wouldn't recommend making any changes since K8s (kube-proxy) is constantly changing the rules dynamically.  In other words, Kubernetes manages (combined with the overlay) manages iptables for you.

To block traffic I would strongly suggest using [NetworkPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). And/Or if you are using an overlay, you can use what that overlay provides. For example, Calico has its own [Network Policy](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/reference/calicoctl/resources/networkpolicy)

Another way of controlling traffic in/out is to use a service-mesh like [Istio](https://istio.io/).

Comment: Thanks but for my knowledge, Network policy __only__ control the connection between `pods` level, but what I need is control the access from `external(internet) ` request. Does it meet the requirement?